# Dynamically reading in a python file and executing it safely

Tags: python

I am writing an app and I want users to be able to input python files for corner cases. In my head the best way I can think of doing this is to save their file to disk and save the location to a DB then dynamically import it using `__import__()` and then execute it. The first part of my question is: is this the best way to do this?

Also, this brings up some pretty big security concerns. Is there a way to run their module under restriction? To not let it see the file system or anything?

**Edit:**

The execution of the python would be to retrieve data from a backend service that is outside the scope of "normal", So it would not be a full application. It could just be a definition of a custom protocol.

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython ... I was gonna put it as an answer ... but really just read this article ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `compile` and `exec` builtins for executing in memory. The downside is that you don't get source lines in tracebacks.

Not much hope about security though. Even if you put ridiculously restrictive filters in place, like restricting everything to a single expression and removing most built-in functions, [arbitrary code can be executed](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Prohibiting file system access, or access to other OS resources, is also hard from within Python, as the code would run in the same process. A child process with severe restrictions (`chroot` jail, `ulimit`, etc.) is a possibility, but that's not only a lot of work, it also rules out most means of interaction with the host application.

If your application runs locally and with the same permissions as the user's account, it's probably best not to worry and give them more power, as they can't do anything/much they couldn't do anyway, and most restriction would make the task (whatever it is) harder/more annoying. If, on the other hand, the code would execute on a server or something, **forget about** running it in the same process.

Comment: I'm thinking I can spawn a sandboxed instance of the jvm and run jython in it. That way, I can take user code in more than just python. Does that make sense? I also came across [pysandbox](https://github.com/haypo/pysandbox), but I'm not sure how legit it is.

Comment: @sir_charles804 Sounds feasible. I'd be weary of rolling something like this myself though, much opportunity to screw up. That said, I'd also carefully inspect of any third party project doing this (such as `pysandbox`).

Comment: I agree. I think if I do this it will be with a VM. That way I trust the container. I haven't decided that this is the way I'm going to let users specify connections for corner cases or not yet, but your input was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do several things to limit powers (see my comment on OP)

but really my two cents ... just give each user their own VM (maybe AWS?) ... that way they cant screw up much... and you can always just restart it ...

a more complicated approach (but arguably cooler) would be to use lex/yacc (in python its PLY) and define your own language (which could be a limited subset of python)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider following method

```
class _DynamicModule(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def load(self, code):
        execdict = {'__builtins__': __builtins__}
        exec compile(code, '<string>', 'exec') in execdict
        for key in execdict:
            if not key.startswith('_'):
                if not isinstance(execdict[key], str):
                    execdict[key].__module__ = self._name
                setattr(self, key, execdict[key])
        return self

import sys
sys.modules['dummy_modules'] = _DynamicModule('dummy_modules').load('print ("!")')
```

This still has pretty big security concerns.